# How to disable ipv4 in squid proxy?

Tags: ubuntu, squid

How do I disable ipv4 in squid proxy so when I visit a site it will use ipv6 ip only. I install squid proxy on ubuntu 20.04. I tested my config but on whatismyipaddress.com it can still detect ipv4. Here's my config

```
forwarded_for off
via off
follow_x_forwarded_for deny all
request_header_access X-Forwarded-For deny all
request_header_access From deny all
request_header_access Referer deny all
request_header_access User-Agent deny all
request_header_access Authorization allow all
request_header_access Proxy-Authorization allow all
request_header_access Cache-Control allow all
request_header_access Content-Length allow all
request_header_access Content-Type allow all
request_header_access Date allow all
request_header_access Host allow all
request_header_access If-Modified-Since allow all
request_header_access Pragma allow all
request_header_access Accept allow all
request_header_access Accept-Charset allow all
request_header_access Accept-Encoding allow all
request_header_access Accept-Language allow all
request_header_access Connection allow all
request_header_access All deny all

acl localnet src xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
acl localnet src xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx

acl ipv4_from src ipv4
acl ipv4_to dst ipv4

acl ip1 myip 2406:cb42:0:1029:607a:0000:0000:0001
acl ip2 myip 2406:cb42:0:1029:607a:0000:0000:0002  

tcp_outgoing_address 2406:cb42:0:1029:607a:0000:0000:0001 ip1
tcp_outgoing_address 2406:cb42:0:1029:607a:0000:0000:0002 ip2

http_access allow localnet
http_access allow localhost
http_access deny all
http_access deny ipv4_from
http_access deny ipv4_to

acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80      # http
acl Safe_ports port 21      # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443     # https
acl Safe_ports port 70      # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210     # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280     # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488     # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591     # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777     # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

http_port 3128
```

Answer (score 1):

```
acl ipv4_from src ipv4
acl ipv4_to dst ipv4

http_access deny ipv4_from
http_access deny ipv4_to
http_access allow localhost
http_access deny all
```

This Squid ACL fragment prohibits all IPv4, and only allows to localhost, so a squid running on the local box. (Compiled in special ACL strings exist for all of ["ipv4"](https://github.com/squid-cache/squid/blob/SQUID_5_0_4/src/acl/Ip.cc#L246) or "ipv6".)   Adjust as desired, perhaps allow from your organization's /48 prefix.

Denying v4 destinations will prevent access to IPv4 only sites, even if the squid host is dual stack and can reach them. This is fine if you want to force a v6 only environment.  But will deny things including, as of 2021, serverfault.com.

Or, could configure the hosts with IPv6 only networking.

Comment: I tried but it still doesn't work. On whatismyipaddress.com it can detect ipv4. I've updated my fist post to include my config

Answer (score 0):

I've tested the following config file which worked to only allow IPv6 traffic:

```
acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8
acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12
acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16
acl localnet src fc00::/7
acl localnet src fe80::/10
acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80
acl Safe_ports port 21
acl Safe_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 70
acl Safe_ports port 210
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535
acl Safe_ports port 280
acl Safe_ports port 488
acl Safe_ports port 591
acl Safe_ports port 777
acl CONNECT method CONNECT
acl ipv4_from src ipv4
acl ipv4_to dst ipv4
dns_v4_first off
acl to_ipv6 dst ipv6
http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager
http_access deny !Safe_ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
http_access deny ipv4_to
http_access deny ipv4_from
http_access deny !to_ipv6
http_access allow to_ipv6
http_access allow localnet
http_access allow localhost
http_access deny all
http_port 3128
coredump_dir /var/cache/squid
refresh_pattern ^ftp: 1440 20% 10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher: 1440 0% 1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0 0% 0
refresh_pattern . 0 20% 4320
dns_nameservers 2620:fe::fe
max_filedescriptors 3200
```

I confirmed it on https://www.iplocation.net/myip and found correctly no ip4 address but a fully working ipv6 address.

They key sections are the deny at *http_access* level on **ipv4_to** and **ipv4_from** and reverse rule **!to_ipv6**

Note: The DNS server is also setup to use IPv6 server.